# Unable to runs scons getting import error

Tags: python, scons

I have installed scons 2.3.2 and have python 2.4.

When I run scons, I am seeing the following error:

```
scons
Import failed. Unable to find SCons files in:
  /usr/bin/../engine
  /usr/bin/scons-local-2.3.2
  /usr/bin/scons-local
  /usr/lib/scons-2.3.2
  /usr/lib/scons-2.3.2
  /usr/local/lib/scons-2.3.2
  /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/scons-2.3.2
  /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/scons-2.3.2
  /usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/scons-2.3.2
  /usr/lib64/scons-2.3.2
  /usr/lib/scons
  /usr/lib/scons
  /usr/local/lib/scons
  /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/scons
  /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/scons
  /usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/scons
  /usr/lib64/scons
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/scons", line 190, in ?
    import SCons.Script
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/__init__.py", line 76, in ?
    import SCons.Environment
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Environment.py", line 48, in ?
    import SCons.Defaults
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Defaults.py", line 52, in ?
    import SCons.Tool
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Tool/__init__.py", line 50, in ?
    import SCons.Scanner.C
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Scanner/C.py", line 36, in ?
    import SCons.cpp
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/cpp.py", line 398
    p = self.stack[-1] if self.stack else self.default_table
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I did a find and found that SCons is present in /usr/lib/scons. I am not sure why scons is not able to pick it up.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem (from the bottom of the traceback) is a Syntax error:

```
    p = self.stack[-1] if self.stack else self.default_table
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is because you are running a version of Python that doesn't support conditional expressions:

Support for this syntax was added in 2.5, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)

Comment: Thanks! The scons website mentioned python 2.4 is sufficient

Comment: Hmm. That may be because in [PEP 308](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) it is stated in an early draft that this would be implemented in 2.4.

Comment: Please note that the SCons 2.3.2 (once it's running properly) should also warn you that all pre-2.7 versions of Python are deprecated. Python 2.7 is the floor version for development now, because we're moving towards a combined Python2+3 source code base.