# SCons ImportError - No module named SCons.Script‏

Tags: python, scons

I have been trying to get SCons working now for quite a time, but didn't succeed yet. Before everything else: I'm running Windows 7 x64.

I have firstly installed Python 2.7.11 in `C:\Software\Python27` and added both that directory as `C:\Software\Python\Scripts` to
the system path (for all users, that is). Then I installed SCons in `C:\Software\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.4.1`, and
the scripts in the previous mentioned scripts-directory (the directories which the SCons installation msi defaults to).

And now when I try to run SCons I get this error message:

> Import failed. Unable to find SCons files in:
>
> ...
>
> ImportError: No module named SCons.Script

[image: Import failed. Unable to find SCons files in]

As a user I really don't have any idea where the error comes from, other than that SCons can't resolve it's own imports.

I got it working by creating though by creating a new folder: `C:\Software\Python27\Scripts\scons-local` and moving the
contents of the SCons installation folder (`...\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.4.1`) to the newly created folder. But this
gives me a syntax error:

[image: SyntaxError: invalid syntax]

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24796186/unable-to-runs-scons-getting-import-error) that this error is due to my Python version not supporting conditional expressions, because this kind of
expressions are supported from Python 2.4 and higher. The thing is though that I am using Python 2.7.11, and thus I shouldn't get
this error.

[image: Python version]

Some help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you install SCons?

Comment: I think I used the Windows installer, but I'm not sure. It's a long time ago. I'll try to reproduce this error next weekend on my new machine.

Comment: Recommended install method is now to use pip install scons. Just make sure you have newest pip (python -m pip install -U pip)

Answer (score 0):

The windows installer is no longer supported.
The best way to install SCons is now via pip

so:

`python -Mpip install SCons`

Note you will need Python 3.5 or newer (though at this point I'd suggest 3.10 or newer)